# Python: Time and space complexity of gcd and recursive iterations

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I’m studying for mid-terms and this is one of the questions from a past yr paper in university. (Questions stated below)
Given Euclid’s algorithm, we can write the function gcd.

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a%b)
```

[Reduced Proper Fraction]
Consider the fraction, n/d , where n and d are positive integers.
If n < d and GCD(n,d) = 1, it is called a reduced proper fraction.
If we list the set of reduced proper fractions for n <=8 in ascending order of size, we get:
1/8,1/7,1/6,1/5,1/4,2/7,1/3,3/8,2/5,3/7,1/2,4/7,3/5,5/8,2/3,5/7,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/7,7/8
It can be seen that there are 21 elements in this set.

Implement the function count_fraction that takes an integer n and returns the number of reduced proper fractions for n. Assuming that the order of growth (in time) for gcd is O(logn), what is the order of growth in terms of time and space for the function you wrote in Part (B) in terms of n. Explain your answer.

Suggested answer.

```
def count_fraction(n):
    if n==1:
        return 0
    else:
        new = 0
        for i in range(1,n):
            if gcd(i,n) == 1:
                new += 1
        return new + count_fraction(n-1)
```

The suggested answer is pretty strange as the trend of this question in previous years, is designed to test purely recursive/purely iterative solutions, but it gave a mix. Nevertheless, I don’t understand why the suggested order of growth is given as such. (I will write it in the format, suggested answer, my answer and questions on my fundamentals)

Time: O(nlogn), since it’s roughly log1+log2+· · ·+log(n−1)+logn

> My time: O(n^2 log n). Since there is n recursive function calls, each call has n-1 iterations, which takes O(log n) time due to gcd.
>
> Question 1: Time in my opinion is counting number of iterations/recursions* time taken for 1 iteration/recursion. It’s actually my first time interacting with a mixed iterative/recursive solution so I don’t really know the interaction. Can someone tell me whether I'm right/wrong?

Space: O(n), since gcd is O(1) and this code is obviously linear recursion.

> My space: O(n*log n). Since gcd is O(log n) and this code takes up O(n) space.
>
> Question 2: Space in my opinion is counting number of recursions*space taken for 1 recursive call OR largest amount of space required among all iterations. In the first place, I would think gcd is O(log n) as I assume that recursion will happen log n times. I want to ask whether the discrepancy is due to what my lecturer said.
>
> (I don’t really understand what my lecturers says about delayed operations for recursions on factorial or no new objects being formed in iteratives. How do u then accept the fact that there are NEW objects formed in recursion also no delayed operations in iteration).
>
> If u can clarify my doubt on why gcd is O(1) instead of O(log n), I think if I take n*1 for recursion case, I would agree with the answer.

Comment: This isn't related to your specific complexity question, but the description of the bounds of the problem seems completely wrong. If you're only bounding `n`, then there are an infinite number of proper fractions with `n < d`. Why isn't `1/x` for every single positive `x` value not included in the list? The actual bound seems to be on `d`, not `n`. Or rather, it's on both of them: `n < d <= bound`

Comment: @Blckknght I admit I find the qns unclear too, given from the list they gave me. But I'm just a student, maybe the examiner did not explain the context well enough with text. We should just work with what we have based on the examples? I always do that instead of doubting whether the context seems legit.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your analysis for of the running time. It should be `O(n^2 log(n))`, since you make `n` calls to `gcd` on each recursive call to `count_fraction`.

You're also partly right about the second question, but you get the conclusion wrong (and the supplied answer gets the right conclusion for the wrong reasons). The `gcd` function does indeed use `O(log(n))` space, for the stack of the recursive calls. However, that space gets reused for each later call to gcd from `count_fraction`, so there's only ever one stack of size `log(n)`. So there's no reason to multiply the `log(n)` by anything, only add it to whatever else might be using memory when the `gcd` calls are happening. Since there will also be a stack of size `O(n)` for the recursive calls of `count_fraction`, the smaller `log(n)` term can be dropped, so you say it takes `O(n)` space rather than `O(n + log(n))`.

All in all, I'd say this is a *really* bad assignment to be trying to learn from. Almost everything in it has an error somewhere, from the description saying it's limiting `n` when it's really limiting `d`, to the answers you describe which are all at least partly wrong.

Comment: I think I heard the mention of "space reuse" somewhere before, but I dont know its importance to space complexity.  How do u tell that space gets reused in the call from `count_fraction` to  `gcd`  ? Mind providing an eg of "no space reuse'?





Sry for the weird qns. My university gave me assignments, mostly in the form of mathematics puzzles, like 4 glasses problem, continued fractions,tower of hanoi. And I got past some of them by trying some code I nvr thought would work. My basics on concepts like these are not "covered" or "cultivated", I'm unsure about the right learning method.

Comment: I have more qns on space complexity btw. Maybe u can explain it with this context if u dont mind.
 Thanks for the help.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194892/python-memory-complexity-of-repeated-digit-sumiterative-and-recursive]